# Getting position in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am transforming my ListView to RecyclerView using Support Library v7.

I have 2 different layouts to load in a `RecyclerView`. In `ListView`, I was getting the position of the item in the `getView()` method and able to load an appropriate layout for that row. But in `RecyclerView`the `onCreateViewHolder` doesn't have the position parameter.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

PS:The Inbox app from Google shows different layouts in a `RecyclerView`(might be). I don't think they might have used the `ListView` because of the performance improvements in `RecyclerView`

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v=null;

            MyVO vo = voList.get(???POSITION???);

            switch(vo.getType()){
                case TYPE_1:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout1, viewGroup, false);
                    break;
                case TYPE_2:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout2, viewGroup, false);
                    break;
            }
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
```

Comment: Your second parameter is `viewType`, I think it's what you want.

Comment: That's what I also thought at first. But its not. Its only the type of the view and not the position.

Comment: another way of think: switch(viewType) instead of vo.getType()

Comment: @Mohamed I guess MyVO would be a data model, which holds not only a value but also a type of widget/layout that is to be used to show the value. Typically your dataSet is a collection of primitive values, Sathesh'es is a collection of MyVO's. I am not sure it is great idea to have model per cell, I like the idea of having a model per row.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Firstly, override `getItemViewType` method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //Implement your logic here
    MyVO vo = voList.get(position);
    return vo.getType();
}
```

Then you can simply use the second parameter of the `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v=null;

        switch(viewType){
            case TYPE_1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout1, viewGroup, false);
                break;
            case TYPE_2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout2, viewGroup, false);
                break;
        }
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But the problem is that, after the notifyDataSetChanged() is called, the layout1 elements becomes null and only the layout2 elements are available in the onBindViewHolder()

Comment: This definitely works but not a good solution when a number of data items belong to the same view type (for example in a situation where a header and a footer needs to be added around a list) I'd not want to create cases for every item in the list since all of them belong to same view type.